# Frequency Dictionary from Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe, frequency

I am trying to obtain a frequency count of key-value pairs from a Pandas data frame, using column names as keys.

Although there are several related questions, none really helped me achieve what I wanted, so I wrote a nested for loop to achieve my goal:

```
#first get all key value pairs
d = {}
for var in list(df.columns.values):
    d[var] = df[var].unique().tolist()

#then count
d_num = {}
for k,l in d.iteritems():
    for v in l:
        d_num[(k+'_'+str(v))] = len(df[df[k]==v])


freqs = Counter(d_num.values()).most_common()
```

Obviously, this is slow, but I can't think of a way to do it using vectorized methods. Any ideas?

**Edit:** 
Here is a sample input:

```
   Name Animal Legs Color
0  Foo  Dog    4    Brown
1  Bar  Cat    4    White
2  Baz  Cat    4    Black
3  Foo  Bird   2    Black
4  Foo  Dog    4    White
```

Output (not necessarily a dictionary, and not necessarily with that kind of keys):

```
out = {Name_Foo: 3, Name_Bar:1, Name_Baz:1, Animal_Dog:2, Animal_Cat:2, Animal_Bird:1, Legs_2:1, Legs_4:4, Color_Brown:1, Color_White:2, Color_Black:2}
```

Comment: can you show an input and expected output.  I feel like you are looking for `pd.value_counts(Series)`, but am having a tough time following exactly what you want

Comment: What's wrong with [`value_counts()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts)?

Comment: Just added sample input/output.... Would value_counts() work with many columns?

Comment: `value_counts` operates on a series, you can't call it on a df, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) for each column and assign to this a dict to produce a dict of Series:

```
In [19]:

temp={}
for col in df:
    temp[col] = df[col].value_counts()
temp
Out[19]:
{'Animal': Dog     2
 Cat     2
 Bird    1
 dtype: int64, 'Name': Foo    3
 Baz    1
 Bar    1
 dtype: int64, 'Legs': 4    4
 2    1
 dtype: int64, 'Color': Black    2
 White    2
 Brown    1
 dtype: int64}
In [21]:

temp['Animal']
Out[21]:
Dog     2
Cat     2
Bird    1
dtype: int64
```

If you then wanted to access the 'Dog' count then `temp['Animal']['Dog']` would output 2

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and a much much faster way to do things than my nested for loops. Thanks!